# Do I have to define a new constant To generate a unix file separator with a program run on windows

Tags: java, windows, unix

I need to add a line with a Unix file path, in a program executed on windows. With this configuration, if I use `File.separator` I get the windows' one. Do I have to add a constant like

```
public final static String DIR_SEPARATOR = "/";
```

In my program, or is there already one known?

Comment: If you're only going to use the constant once, then there is no reason to declare it. Have you tried to get the home directory this way: System.getProperty("user.home");

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

File.separator will be always return the OS separator in which the JVM runs.

By the way, the File class will always convert the separator: just try this in a simple program and look at the path created:

```
File file1 = new File("C:\\dir\\test.txt");
File file2 = new File("C:/dir/test.txt"); //same of above
File file3 = new File("/usr/test/dir/test");
File file4 = new File("\\usr\\test\\dir\\test"); //same of above
```